# Is it possible to point a domain name to my Google drive?

Tags: dns, share, google-drive-api, domain-name

Is it possible to point a domain name to my Google drive?

Comment: I have a google account , and I have some files in Google drive , is it possible to point a domain name (www.something.com) to this drive
In an other way using Google drive as web host

Comment: No, not really. You could redirect your site to the URL of the file if it's a public file using `<meta>`, or maybe stream the file, but I don't know what language you are using on your server.

Comment: Thanks for replying<br/>
Could you please give me an example<br/>
I am using PHP/python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) in PHP to do this. Here is the example they give:

```
<?php
    $file = 'monkey.gif';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Replace `monkey.gif` with the URL of the public file.